# What exactly was the nature of the relationship between Jabba the Hutt and Princess Leia?

Tags: star-wars, sexuality

Jabba the Hutt did a couple of things to Princess Leia, that seem rather unusual for the giant worm-like creature that he is, namely:

1. Make her wear a metal bikini.
2. Kiss her

Given these two things, what was the full nature of the relationship between them? Specifically, did Jabba make Leia **perform some sort of sexual acts** with him, or was there something else going on?

From "[Do Hutts find humanoid females attractive, and if so why?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/18427/2565)" we know that a reason for the way Leia was displayed might have to do with a) status and b) Jabba being considered a pervert by some of his fellow Hutt. But this doesn't answer if went any further than this.

Comment: Aside, wasn't this question already addressed on this site?  I vaguely remember Leia's bikini outfit being addressed, with the suggestion that it was similar to us humans dressing up our pets...

Comment: @Izkata, You're probably thinking of [Do Hutts find humanoid females attractive, and if so why?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/18427/5184) - which *does* go into a lot of similar discussion, but doesn't answer the primary question asked here.

Comment: Related Meta Question. http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3043/98

Comment: You may want to check out '*Tales from Jabba's Palace*' and/or '*The Last One Standing: The Tale of Boba Fett*'.  They include details of Leia being stripped and dressed in the 'Slave Girl' clothing, and that she replaced [Oola](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Oola), who '*was forced to dance for him, as well as give pleasure when the depraved crime lord beckoned*' (quote from Wookiepedia; uncertain source.)

Comment: It may also be worth looking at the '*[Han Solo Trilogy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Han_Solo_Trilogy)*', as Wookiepedia attributes the statement '*His humanoid female fetish was also implied by close Hutt associates of Jabba to not be a typical Hutt trait.*' to it.

Comment: I was always under the impression that Leia was there incognito. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @MPelletier http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: @MPelletier She came in incognito, as a bounty hunter, but she was captured when she tried to get Han out.  I'm pretty sure that part wasn't planned.

Comment: @Kevin Good thing she _didn't_ succeed, or C3PO, R2D2, and Chewbacca may have been stuck there.

Comment: This was one of the key scenes in the film -- everyone was fascinated by two utterly different species having an implicitly sexual relationship. Brilliant idea that left for example STOS in the dust -- Kirk conveniently had his pick of not just very humanoid but very attractive alien females: they never explored sex between really different looking species (except maybe energy beings).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In one of the Boba Fett comics, there was a story where three Hutts were competeing with one another to prove who was 'the best' among them. Jabba, of course, had the Fett, and considered himself the superior.

Given this state of thought (ie, warlords, crime lords, and the such), the golden rule of "He who dies with the most toys..." is in full effect. Jabba was said to have several palatial mansions, with many speeders, ships, slaves, bodyguards, and the such. Seriously, he could afford smuggling operations (like Han and Lando) and Boba Fett, who was widely believed to be the best Bounty Hunter in the Galaxy, as a bodyguard.

So, to your question...

Jabba, though a depraved pervert amongst depraved perverts, could not physically have sex with a human due to biological constraints and physical limitations. Though they did not reproduce asexually (again a Boba Fett comic), they could only do so with other Hutts. Now this isn't to say that he couldn't have, say, that pig-faced guard ordered to do the deed and simply watch; Jabba definately strikes me as that kind of slug (pun intended). Leia, after all, is Princess Leia Organa, Princess of (formerly) Alderaan. The metal bikini was a choice of degradation and submission; he was putting her in her place. The chain was to show all that she was his pet slave. Seriously, he fed Oola, the Twi'lek cutie, to a Rancor (wasteful). If he wanted to make an example or an impression, there would be no limit with the Don of Dons in the Star Wars Galaxy.

IMHO, this would *elevate* Jabba's status as he is now the proud owner of a royal member of some form of nobility. Imagine Al Capone having Sarah Fergeson on a chain in a cute little number sitting on the floor next to his throne. Jabba is the pinnacle of crime lords, as even Republic entities tend to tred carefully around him, and Jabba is well known even outside of Hutt space. Jabba was Noriega and Escobar wrapped in Castro cigar.

Jabba the Hutt; innovative designer of female domwear since 3 ABY (1983).

Answer (score 7):

Due to biological reasons it is unlikely he did anything with her himself.

The reason he kept her like that are likely to be:

- As an ornament as she is nice to look at
- As a show of his power over a Princess
- To humiliate her
- To offer her to others in negotiation or as reward

Comment: -1 - EU suggests Jabba had "unnatural practices" and was known among Hutts for keeping dancing girls around.

Comment: Is there any evidence that he knew Leia's actual identity (and that she was a princess)? [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Boushh) mentions that Boushh's armor was discarded after Leia was captured, but makes no mention of her identity being revealed.

Comment: Ooh - that is an interesting question - I had always assumed that he or at least someone in his court would have recognised her but I guess it is not specicified (at least not that I can remember, it is about 10 years since I saw the film last!)

Comment: OK, I checked [the script](http://www.blueharvest.net/scoops/rotj-script.shtml), and Han does exclaim, "Leia!" when he realizes it's her. But I'm still not entirely convinced that Jabba (or anyone else) actually made the connection. Leia makes mention of their "powerful friends" but does not mention her own more immediate connections/status.

Comment: It is a fair point

Answer (score 4):

Nothing is known for certain, so it is possible that Jabba used her sexually, however it is very unlikely.

The Hutts are gastropods, so they reproduce asexually - meaning that they do not have the correct genitalia for this. Any "sexual activities" would have to be restricted to simply touching.
I also think it's unlikely he would bring himself down to the level of sexually interacting with a *slave*, when he is a crime lord. It wouldn't do his image any favour.

As for why he kept her in a bikini - perhaps he wanted to humiliate her (most likely), or he may have had her there for his viewing pleasure.

Comment: Well, maybe he was a voyeur and liked to watch. He'd probably have access to other (male or female) slaves.

Comment: @bitmask - not "probably". Definitely. This was discussed in Han Solo trilogy (e.g. **Hutt Gambit**) and Tales of Jabba's palace.

Comment: @DVK: I suspected as much. However, reconsidering the argument that Jabba wouldn't have reproductive organs physically compatible with humanoids ... he wouldn't really need those to actively participate "sexual activities" in a sufficiently broad sense. Yack, now I require brain bleach.

Comment: @bitmask - I got two words for you. Bill Clinton.

Comment: A (grim) possibility I haven't seen anyone mention is that he MAY have abused her sexually (or had another do so); not out of any desire for such activities, but because he *is* a crime boss, and (especially with someone of high-level upbringing) that's a well know method to break their spirit and establish dominance.  If he *did* know who she was, he could have performed basically meaningless actions on his part that would have horrified her, and used that to gain control over her on multiple levels.  (E.g., How's your reputation in the senate, now that you've been molested by a Hutt?)

Comment: @DVK: Well, Bill Clinton evidently *does* have human reproductive organs, so I don't see the relevance. I should note that I really couldn't care less regarding the private lives of any politician in general. They should be measured and remembered for what they did professionally, not what happened between consenting adults. But in this particular case I don't see the connection at all. So please enlighten us why you keep bringing it up.

Comment: @bitmask - he was the first celebrity to bring to public eye the fact that you can define "sex" in widely varying ways.

Comment: @DVK unlikely to be the first, but the most published certainly and probably the first to use such a differing definition as legal defense.

Comment: Worth noting that whether or not Jabba sees Leia as a sexual object or not, or whether he wants to break her spirit, Leia is a slave girl and thus a symbol of wealth and power. These symbols aren't necessarily just for Jabba, but the people who observe him; an easy way to show that one has wealth, power, and influence, is to flaunt it and put it on display. It'd be like buying a Bugatti to show off to the world, only to keep it in your garage with your Ferrari and your Lambo.

Comment: @lunchmeat317 - nope. Jabba was a Hutt. He only cared what other Hutts thought. And they thought his fascination with humanoids was highly unnatural. Ref: EU

Comment: Hutts appear to share some of the characteristics of gastropods on Earth but they are clearly NOT gastropods and although they hermaphroditic so they also do not exclusively reproduce asexually.