# Do other Hutts consider Jabba a sexual deviant?

Tags: star-wars, jabba-the-hutt

I recall pre-Disney sources stating that Jabba's "attraction to humanoid females was something of a personal fetish, the other Hutts considered it abnormal"- does this hold up in the new canon?

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/18427/57310 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/37895/57310. Borderline dupe to the second (it also asks "Jabba being considered a pervert by some of his fellow Hutt").

Comment: "Jabba the Slutt"...?

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, such a statement has not been made. In fact, there's arguably evidence to the contrary.

For one, scantily clad Twi'lek were seen dancing for the Grand Hutt Council. While Jabba headed the council, this entertainment choice could suggest that the others at least tolerated it. The dancers are seen flirting with a few council members, who respond positively.

[image]

Ziro also had a relationship with Sy Snootles, proving that inter-species relationships were not unheard of among other Hutts.

[image]

Comment: Not unheard of doesn't mean common, and it's possible the other hutts in the council just chose to humor Jabba.