# Why did Jabba the Hutt enslave Leia?

Tags: star-wars

Why did Jabba make Leia his slave?

Comment: Rule #34. http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/rule-34 (possibly adult content)

Comment: Have you seen her in that bikini? Why wouldn't he enslave her?

Comment: "Disney owning it now it not an indicator that it will become less childish and illogical." It's also not an indicator that it *will*. Disney hasn't made Marvel comics or movies any more childish or illogical. Disney also owned Miramax until 2010, which had plenty of very adult-themed movies.

Answer (score 1):

Jabba was notorious for keeping humanoid females as trophies or pets (see the question [Do Hutts find humanoid females attractive?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18427/do-hutts-find-humanoid-females-attractive-and-if-so-why) for details). He was also notorious for being hedonistic and quite sadistic - even by Hutt standards - as well as intelligent & under-handed. Also, one of the many things Jabba dealt in was information brokering, so we can assume he knew who Leia was. Understanding this, we can come up with the following reasons:

- A trophy: Nothing says "status symbol" like the Princess of Alderaan chained to your dais and scrubbing your back.
- Personal pleasure: As mentioned in the other question, Jabba had a thing for humanoid females - not necessarily on a sexual level (although possibly) - but definitely on a decoration or collection level. Again, nothing says "I'm awesome" like having a princess in your personal harem.
- Sadism & Gloating: Another possibility is that Jabba wanted to keep her hostage, perhaps to ransom off to Vader later, but enjoyed debasing royalty by putting her in such a situation. Think of it as making the king of a planet your shoe-shine boy or something - not only could you enjoy watching him grovel, but it also doubles as a statement that says "I'm more powerful than a KING."