# Are Bajorans of human origin?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

A recall at least two or three examples in Deep Space 9 (one in [Shakaar](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shakaar_(episode)) episode), when major Kira is asking Odo about some strange behavior observed among their own people (Bajorans) and Odo replies, that "humans usually...".

Is this only a glitch or should this suggest, that Bajorans are of human orgin? Or is there anything else that explains, why Bajorans behavior would be so extremely similar (according to Odo) to make an equation mark between it and human behavior.

Comment: Can you reference the exact cases? (chakoteya.net) I don't see the word human in the transcript for "Shakaar"

Comment: [The "Wardroom" section](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/470.htm)'s last sentence: `ODO: It has been my observation that one of the prices of giving people freedom of choice is that sometimes they make the wrong choice`. I hope I did not misunderstand word "people" in here.

Comment: @trejder: "People" generally refers to members of any sapient species, not just humans, in works in which this makes a difference.

Comment: (I'm rewatching DS9) Odo usually and noticeably is quite careful to say "humanoids" when talking to Kira (and others? But, he usually is talking to Kira) about such things.  Seems like a glitch to me.  Of course it would make sense if he said "humans usually do X, but I've noticed you Bajorans don't", but I haven't seen that yet.  - Writing this I notice "humanoids" is itself kind of race-specific.  I put this down to some sort of translation issue between what Odo said, and what we hear translated.  (Surely Kira and Odo speak Bajoran between themselves?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## No.

Bajorans don't originate with humans, but they likely share a common history.

See [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/6677/3823) to this question:

[Is the humanoid appearance of most alien species in the Star Trek universe ever canonically addressed?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6676/is-the-humanoid-appearance-of-most-alien-species-in-the-star-trek-universe-ever/6677#6677)

about the possible common origin with humans.   It's never explicitly stated that this applies to Bajorans, but it does for Cardassians (who are close neighbors) since they appear in the episode "The Chase", and this is the given in-universe explanation for the large number of humanoid aliens in the Alpha and Beta Quadrants.

Here's the answer given in the link:

In *Star Trek: The Next Generation*'s "[The Chase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chase_%28Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation%29)", the Federation, Klingons, Cardassians, and Romulans are all on what amounts to a treasure hunt:

> Representatives of all three races are together when all the pieces are put together and it turns out to be a program that takes over a tricorder and projects an image of an ancient alien who tells them that they found the galaxy empty, other than themselves, so they spread seeds of DNA throughout so there would be other races and that the existing races would be descendants of that seeding.

I would also add that Bajor has a [history](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bajoran#Ancient_Bajor) dating way before any high civilization on Earth (25,000 years), and there has never been a fallen space-faring *human* civilization posited this early from Earth in the *Star Trek* universe.

However, there are also [the Preservers](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Preservers), possibly or possibly not the same race as in "The Chase", that could have transplanted humans to Bajor early on, but there has never been a suggestion in-universe that this occurred or any suggestion that Bajorans didn't evolve on Bajor.

Comment: Can you reference the exact cases?  (chakoteya.net)   I don't see the word human in the transcript for "Shakaar".

Comment: This is right. The same thing applies to real-world human ethnic groups. Genetic, cultural, and linguistic evidence indicates that Celtic and Latin peoples share a common origin, but it is not correct to say that one derived from the other. Rather, they both descend from the Bronze Age Proto-Indo-Europeans.