# What's the in-universe explanation for why most aliens are humanoid in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

In *Star Trek*, [there's an in-universe explanation for why most aliens have a humanoid appearance](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6676/is-the-humanoid-appearance-of-most-alien-species-in-the-star-trek-universe-ever). Is there an explanation for why it is also the case in the MCU and other versions of the Marvel universe?

Comment: Easier to draw in the comics?

Comment: I'd say thankfully no, but there's probably something somewhere in the comics.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears to be because the Celestials manipulated life throughout the universe to be in their form to protect their embryos. As shown in *Eternals Vol 1* #1 they created three races on Earth in their image: the Deviant, the Human and the Eternal.

[image: Eternals Vol 1 page showing the Celestials creation of the races]

That shows they used apes as the main life form to create these species but they also did it on other planets where apes were likely not present and so they modelled them after their own image. This is shown in the alternate universe Earth-9997 and in *Earth X* we see the description.

[image: Page showing the Celestials creating races]

In the MCU I'm pretty sure nothing about this has been said yet, or at least I can't find anything. Will update if I find any new information though I doubt there will be any.

Comment: Great answer, and this is so close to the Star Trek reasons it's funny

Comment: @GordonBennett Also similar to Dr Who's expanded universe explanation (at least in the BF audio plays), except there is was essentially because the architect of timelord society was a massive racist with a God complex who wanted to force intelligent life to evolve in their image.